# Can I mark text in Word such that I can filter it?

Tags: ms-word

so I'm writing a project in Word. Throughout the document I'll be referring to different topics e.g. finances, people etc. 
Is there any way that I could mark the text such that when the project is complete I can view all the sections discussing finances or specific people? Sort of like using the filter function in excel.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The nearest Word has for that are the Table of Contents, which links to individual headings, or an Index, which lists the page(s) on which a tagged entry appears. Unlike a Table of Contents, though, Index entries don't link to the tagged content.